# MSI upgrade with Powershell /DSC

Tags: powershell, dsc

I am able to successfully uninstall (Ensure = "Absent") or install a product (Ensure = "Present"). However, if I create a new version of the same product, it always comes back with the same message - "already installed".

Does that mean the only way to upgrade is to uninstall / install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is an MSI that you are creating. Make sure you're [changing the product code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx) for each version:

> ***What is ProductCode in MSI Package?***
>
> The product code is the unique GUID of identifying an application or
>   product release; In other words, different versions and languages of
>   Product must have different product codes.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370854(VS.85).aspx. Also,
>   ProductCode can be used to query feature state, and product state. For
>   example,  installer API "MsiQueryFeatureStateEx()" and
>   "MsiQueryProductState()", etc.

Comment: Check the link (the first link, not the one in the quote) and have a look at *UpgradeCode*. By ensuring that the *same* upgrade code is used, it should not install as a new product.

Comment: You are correct - the only thing I need to make sure is to use the new ProductCode in the ps1/MOF file.

Comment: Yes, you would have to change the product code, and therefore change your conifg and recompile to MOF for each new version.